# Jquery slideToggle particular div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery-ui

Respected ppl ...

This is my markup :

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12 card card-even">
      <div>
        <h3>Case 1</h3>
        <a href="" class="hiderBUTTON">Hide the subsection</a>
      </div>
        <div class = "timeline">
          <div class= "circle circle-green "  data-toggle="tooltip" title="Task 2 ">
            <span></span>
          </div>
          <div class="rect-fixed"></div>
        </div>
      <div class="subsection"><span>Panther a</span></div>
    </div> <!-- end of card 1-->
  </div>
 <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12 card card-odd">
      <div>
        <h3>Case 1</h3>
        <a href="" class="hiderBUTTON">Hide the subsection</a>
      </div>
        <div class = "timeline">
          <div class= "circle circle-green "  data-toggle="tooltip" title="Task 2 ">
            <span></span>
          </div>
          <div class="rect-fixed"></div>
        </div>
      <div class="subsection"><span>Panther b</span></div>
    </div> <!-- end of card 2-->
  </div>
```

I have an app which generates multiple alternating cards(row-fluids) which are even/odd with a button "hiderBUTTON" to hide the div with the class=subsection

But im unable to link the button of a particular row with its corresponding subsection ....

How do i use the this keyword correctly and target a button's subsection for a given row ...

Thanks very much ....

Regards

Comment: Please, if possible, next time put a code (even if errata) of what you've tried, so not only we'll provide you with a fully working one, but perhaps with only a minor fix of yours and with additional suggestions on what you should take care in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
$('.hiderBUTTON').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).closest('.card').find('.subsection').toggle();
});
```

Use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get to the its root parent of each subsection and button parent i.e `.card` and the use find to get the `subsection` and use toggle to switch it or just use .hide() to hide it.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Z8vDP/)**

With text toggling b/w show/hide

```
$('.hiderBUTTON').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.closest('.card').find('.subsection').toggle();
    $this.text(function(_, text){
        return text == "Hide the subsection" ? "Show the subsection" : "Hide the subsection";
    })
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nUT49/)**

Comment: Sir ... any idea how i could keep all the subsections hidden by default in the start ? ... thanks once again ...